# how to pass args to a struct MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a struct , its fields can take a value or a list of values ,e xample

```
myStruct.file 
myStruct.format
```

the value of myStruct.file can be :  one file or a list of files
the value of myStruct.format can be one format or a list of formats : txt,xml,.c

so if I try in the case of a list of files :

```
myStruct.file = {'file1','file2'}
if strcmp(x,1)
subFiles = {fullfile(myStruct.file, 'toto','control.txt'),fullfile(myStruct.file, 'toto','model.txt')};
for m=1:numel(subFiles)
....
end
```

do you know how this can be implemented ?
any suggession ?
Thanks,
Regards

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Can you explain "myStruct.file can take one file or a list of files myStruct.format can take one format or a list of formats : txt,xml,.c" a bit better? What do you mean by "take one file"? Does it mean a filename? Same for `format`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cell arrays:

```
myStruct = struct;
myStruct.file = {'file1','file2',...};
myStruct.format = {'format1','format2',...};
```